# Reading second stage bootloader from FAT floppy image

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, osdev, fat

I am trying to develop a small OS with custom bootloader. I have a little bit of experience in OSDEV but not that much... My problem is that the first stage bootloader does not load the seconds from the disk. this is the boot.asm file:

```
org 0
bits 16

jmp boot

%include "include/fat12.inc"
%include "include/io.inc"

Mem.Loader1 equ 0x00007c00
Mem.Loader1.Size equ 0x00000200
Mem.Loader1.Segment equ Mem.Loader1 >> 4
Mem.Stack.Top equ 0x00007c00

boot: jmp Mem.Loader1.Segment : .init
.init:

cli

; adjust segment registers
mov ax, cs
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax

; create stack
xor ax, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, Mem.Stack.Top

sti

call LoadRoot
xor ebx, ebx
mov bp, secondStage
mov si, ImageName
call LoadFile
cmp ax, 0
je secondStage
BiosPrint msgBooting
jmp $
 
msgBooting db "E", 0
ImageName db "loader bin"
 
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

secondStage:
```

Yout may recognize some bits of code from [MonkOS](https://github.com/beevik/MonkOS) and [Brokenthorn](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/) since all my knowledge comes from them and [OSDevWiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/).

The bootloader fails to find the loader.bin file and print the "E".
I am absolutely sure that `LoadRoot` and `LoadFile` works since I've copied it from my last project which worked fine but if necessary I'll add them here.

After assembling the files with nasm I create a floppy image as so:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=BonsOS.img bs=1024 count=1440
/sbin/mkfs.msdos BonsOS.img
mcopy -i BonsOS.img ./bin/boot/loader.bin ::/
dd if=./bin/boot/boot.bin of=BonsOS.img seek=0 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

and finally run

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -fda BonsOS.img -m 512M -no-reboot -no-shutdown
```

How can I fix the file not found problem?

**EDIT**

fat12.inc:

```
;*******************************************************
;
;   Fat12.inc
;       FAT12 filesystem for 3-1/2 floppies
;
;   OS Development Series
;*******************************************************

%ifndef __FAT12_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__
%define __FAT12_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__

bits    16

%include "include/floppy16.inc"                 ; the erm.. floppy driver

%define ROOT_OFFSET 0x2e00
%define FAT_SEG 0x2c0
%define ROOT_SEG 0x2e0

;*******************************************
; LoadRoot ()
;   - Load Root Directory Table to 0x7e00
;*******************************************

LoadRoot:

    pusha                           ; store registers
    push    es

     ; compute size of root directory and store in "cx"
     
    xor     cx, cx                      ; clear registers
    xor     dx, dx
    mov     ax, 32                  ; 32 byte directory entry
    mul     WORD [bpbRootEntries]               ; total size of directory
    div     WORD [bpbBytesPerSector]            ; sectors used by directory
    xchg    ax, cx                      ; move into AX

     ; compute location of root directory and store in "ax"
     
    mov     al, BYTE [bpbNumberOfFATs]          ; number of FATs
    mul     WORD [bpbSectorsPerFAT]             ; sectors used by FATs
    add     ax, WORD [bpbReservedSectors]
    mov     WORD [datasector], ax               ; base of root directory
    add     WORD [datasector], cx

     ; read root directory into 0x7e00
 
    push    word ROOT_SEG
    pop     es
    mov     bx, 0                               ; copy root dir
    call    ReadSectors                         ; read in directory table
    pop     es
    popa                                        ; restore registers and return
    ret

;*******************************************
; LoadFAT ()
;   - Loads FAT table to 0x7c00
;
;   Parm/ ES:DI => Root Directory Table
;*******************************************

LoadFAT:

    pusha                           ; store registers
    push    es

     ; compute size of FAT and store in "cx"
     
    xor     ax, ax
    mov     al, BYTE [bpbNumberOfFATs]          ; number of FATs
    mul     WORD [bpbSectorsPerFAT]             ; sectors used by FATs
    mov     cx, ax

     ; compute location of FAT and store in "ax"

    mov     ax, WORD [bpbReservedSectors]

     ; read FAT into memory (Overwrite our bootloader at 0x7c00)

    push    word FAT_SEG
    pop     es
    xor     bx, bx
    call    ReadSectors
    pop     es
    popa                            ; restore registers and return
    ret
    
;*******************************************
; FindFile ()
;   - Search for filename in root table
;
; parm/ DS:SI => File name
; ret/ AX => File index number in directory table. -1 if error
;*******************************************

FindFile:

    push    cx                      ; store registers
    push    dx
    push    bx
    mov bx, si                      ; copy filename for later

     ; browse root directory for binary image

    mov     cx, WORD [bpbRootEntries]           ; load loop counter
    mov     di, ROOT_OFFSET                     ; locate first root entry at 1 MB mark
    cld                         ; clear direction flag

.LOOP:
    push    cx
    mov     cx, 11                  ; eleven character name. Image name is in SI
    mov si, bx                      ; image name is in BX
    push    di
     rep  cmpsb                         ; test for entry match
    pop     di
    je      .Found
    pop     cx
    add     di, 32                  ; queue next directory entry
    loop    .LOOP

.NotFound:
    pop bx                      ; restore registers and return
    pop dx
    pop cx
    mov ax, -1                      ; set error code
    ret

.Found:
    pop ax                      ; return value into AX contains entry of file
    pop bx                      ; restore registers and return
    pop dx
    pop cx
    ret

;*******************************************
; LoadFile ()
;   - Load file
; parm/ ES:SI => File to load
; parm/ EBX:BP => Buffer to load file to
; ret/ AX => -1 on error, 0 on success
; ret/ CX => number of sectors read
;*******************************************

LoadFile:

    xor ecx, ecx        ; size of file in sectors
    push    ecx

.FIND_FILE:

    push    bx          ; BX=>BP points to buffer to write to; store it for later
    push    bp
    call    FindFile        ; find our file. ES:SI contains our filename
    cmp ax, -1
    jne .LOAD_IMAGE_PRE
    pop bp
    pop bx
    pop ecx
    mov ax, -1
    ret

.LOAD_IMAGE_PRE:

    sub edi, ROOT_OFFSET
    sub eax, ROOT_OFFSET

    ; get starting cluster

    push    word ROOT_SEG       ;root segment loc
    pop es
    mov dx, WORD [es:di + 0x001A]; DI points to file entry in root directory table. Refrence the table...
    mov WORD [cluster], dx  ; file's first cluster
    pop bx          ; get location to write to so we dont screw up the stack
    pop es
    push    bx          ; store location for later again
    push    es
    call    LoadFAT

.LOAD_IMAGE:

    ; load the cluster

    mov ax, WORD [cluster]  ; cluster to read
    pop es          ; bx:bp=es:bx
    pop bx
    call    ClusterLBA
    xor cx, cx
    mov     cl, BYTE [bpbSectorsPerCluster]
    call    ReadSectors
    pop ecx
    inc ecx         ; add one more sector to counter
    push    ecx
    push    bx
    push    es
    mov ax, FAT_SEG     ;start reading from fat
    mov es, ax
    xor bx, bx

    ; get next cluster

    mov     ax, WORD [cluster]  ; identify current cluster
    mov     cx, ax          ; copy current cluster
    mov     dx, ax
    shr     dx, 0x0001      ; divide by two
    add     cx, dx          ; sum for (3/2)

    mov bx, 0           ;location of fat in memory
    add bx, cx
    mov dx, WORD [es:bx]
    test    ax, 0x0001      ; test for odd or even cluster
    jnz .ODD_CLUSTER

.EVEN_CLUSTER:

    and dx, 0000111111111111b   ; take low 12 bits
    jmp .DONE

.ODD_CLUSTER:

    shr dx, 0x0004      ; take high 12 bits

.DONE:

    mov WORD [cluster], dx
    cmp dx, 0x0ff0      ; test for end of file marker
    jb  .LOAD_IMAGE

.SUCCESS:
    pop es
    pop bx
    pop ecx
    xor ax, ax
    ret

%endif      ;__FAT12_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__
```

Which relies on floppy16.inc:

```
;*******************************************************
;
;   Floppy16.inc
;       Floppy drive interface routines
;
;   OS Development Series
;*******************************************************

%ifndef __FLOPPY16_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__
%define __FLOPPY16_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__

bits    16

bpbOEM          db "My OS   "
bpbBytesPerSector:      DW 512
bpbSectorsPerCluster:   DB 1
bpbReservedSectors:     DW 1
bpbNumberOfFATs:    DB 2
bpbRootEntries:     DW 224
bpbTotalSectors:    DW 2880
bpbMedia:       DB 0xf0  ;; 0xF1
bpbSectorsPerFAT:   DW 9
bpbSectorsPerTrack:     DW 18
bpbHeadsPerCylinder:    DW 2
bpbHiddenSectors:   DD 0
bpbTotalSectorsBig:     DD 0
bsDriveNumber:          DB 0
bsUnused:       DB 0
bsExtBootSignature:     DB 0x29
bsSerialNumber:         DD 0xa0a1a2a3
bsVolumeLabel:          DB "MOS FLOPPY "
bsFileSystem:           DB "FAT12   "

datasector  dw 0x0000
cluster     dw 0x0000

absoluteSector db 0x00
absoluteHead   db 0x00
absoluteTrack  db 0x00

;************************************************;
; Convert CHS to LBA
; LBA = (cluster - 2) * sectors per cluster
;************************************************;

ClusterLBA:
          sub     ax, 0x0002                          ; zero base cluster number
          xor     cx, cx
          mov     cl, BYTE [bpbSectorsPerCluster]     ; convert byte to word
          mul     cx
          add     ax, WORD [datasector]               ; base data sector
          ret

;************************************************;
; Convert LBA to CHS
; AX=>LBA Address to convert
;
; absolute sector = (logical sector / sectors per track) + 1
; absolute head   = (logical sector / sectors per track) MOD number of heads
; absolute track  = logical sector / (sectors per track * number of heads)
;
;************************************************;

LBACHS:
          xor     dx, dx                              ; prepare dx:ax for operation
          div     WORD [bpbSectorsPerTrack]           ; calculate
          inc     dl                                  ; adjust for sector 0
          mov     BYTE [absoluteSector], dl
          xor     dx, dx                              ; prepare dx:ax for operation
          div     WORD [bpbHeadsPerCylinder]          ; calculate
          mov     BYTE [absoluteHead], dl
          mov     BYTE [absoluteTrack], al
          ret


;************************************************;
; Reads a series of sectors
; CX=>Number of sectors to read
; AX=>Starting sector
; ES:EBX=>Buffer to read to
;************************************************;

ReadSectors:
     .MAIN
          mov     di, 0x0005                          ; five retries for error
     .SECTORLOOP
          push    ax
          push    bx
          push    cx
          call    LBACHS                              ; convert starting sector to CHS
          mov     ah, 0x02                            ; BIOS read sector
          mov     al, 0x01                            ; read one sector
          mov     ch, BYTE [absoluteTrack]            ; track
          mov     cl, BYTE [absoluteSector]           ; sector
          mov     dh, BYTE [absoluteHead]             ; head
          mov     dl, BYTE [bsDriveNumber]            ; drive
          int     0x13                                ; invoke BIOS
          jnc     .SUCCESS                            ; test for read error
          xor     ax, ax                              ; BIOS reset disk
          int     0x13                                ; invoke BIOS
          dec     di                                  ; decrement error counter
          pop     cx
          pop     bx
          pop     ax
          jnz     .SECTORLOOP                         ; attempt to read again
          int     0x18
     .SUCCESS
          pop     cx
          pop     bx
          pop     ax
          add     bx, WORD [bpbBytesPerSector]        ; queue next buffer
          inc     ax                                  ; queue next sector
          loop    .MAIN                               ; read next sector
          ret

%endif      ;__FLOPPY16_INC_67343546FDCC56AAB872_INCLUDED__
```

This two files are not my code, they are taken from [Brokenthorn](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/) explainations.

Finally io.inc:

```
;************************;
; Parameters:            ;
;   si => string pointer ;
;************************;
bits 16
%macro BiosPrint 1
    mov si, word %1
    call _BiosPrint
%endmacro

_BiosPrint:
    pusha
    .loop:
        lodsb
        or al, al
        jz .done
        mov ah, 0x0E
        int 0x10
        jmp .loop
    .done:
    popa
    ret
```

**EDIT2**
This is the repo for the full project organized: https://github.com/Bonfra04/BonsOS

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for the feedback, I've just edited the post providing the minimal code to reproduce

Comment: @MichaelPetch not really sure what i clicked I'm kinda new to this site.. anyway to your comment wich i deleted(?) I responded "Contains just a simple print function with bios; just added"

Comment: @MichaelPetch In the first lines of boot.asm after the includes I've provided the important part of mem.inc (Mem.Loader1.Segment, Mem.Stack.Top)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Did you find anything? I am adding to the post a link to the github repository for the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a Debugger like BOCHS

I'd highly recommend using BOCHS to debug real mode code, especially bootloaders and the early stages of kernel development. On a *nix type system you could start BOCHS with:

```
bochs -f /dev/null 'floppya: 1_44=BonsOS.img, status=inserted' 'boot: a'
```

Then set a breakpoint at the start of the bootloader and start executing with:

```
b 0x7c00
c
```

Instructions on using BOCHS for stepping; tracing; displaying segment registers; displaying general purpose registers etc. can be found in the [BOCHS documentation](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html).

---

### The Problems

It appears at some point you changed the code to handle the segments differently and introduced some bugs. As well you are searching for the wrong file name. FAT12 file names are stored in all upper case and they are 11 bytes long (8 characters for file name padded with spaces) followed by the 3 letter extension. Your code is looking for:

```
ImageName db "loader bin"
```

When it should be:

```
ImageName db "LOADER  BIN"  ; 2 spaces between LOADER and BIN
```

When calling `LoadFile` you set up the call this way:

```
xor ebx, ebx
mov bp, secondStage
mov si, ImageName
call LoadFile
```

*BX:BP* is supposed to be the segment:offset address where stage2 is to be read into memory. It should be:

```
mov bx, Mem.Loader1.Segment
mov bp, secondStage
mov si, ImageName
call LoadFile
```

It seems like you amended `FindFile` to use `ROOT_OFFSET` while `LoadFat` and `LoadRoot` you use `ROOT_SEG`. Your code ends up having incorrect *DS:SI* and *ES:DI* values for the `CMPSB` instruction so you end up doing string comparisons from the wrong memory addresses. I modified your `FindFile` code to use `ROOT_SEG` and end up with something that looks like:

```
FindFile:

    push    es                           ; Save ES
    push    cx                           ; store registers
    push    dx
    push    bx
    mov bx, si                           ; copy filename for later

     ; browse root directory for binary image
    mov ax, ROOT_SEG                     ; Set ES to ROOT_SEG not 0
    mov es, ax

    mov     cx, WORD [bpbRootEntries]    ; load loop counter
    xor     di, di                       ; Start at 0 offset from ES (ROOT_SEG)
; Remove   mov     di, ROOT_OFFSET       ; locate first root entry
    cld                                  ; clear direction flag

.LOOP:
    push    cx
    mov     cx, 11                       ; eleven character name. Image name is in SI
    mov si, bx                           ; image name is in BX
    push    di
     rep  cmpsb                          ; test for entry match
    pop     di
    je      .Found
    pop     cx
    add     di, 32                       ; queue next directory entry
    loop    .LOOP

.NotFound:
    pop bx                               ; restore registers and return
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop es                               ; Restore ES
    mov ax, -1                           ; set error code
    ret

.Found:
    pop ax                               ; return value into AX contains entry of file
    pop bx                               ; restore registers and return
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop es                               ; Restore ES
    ret
```

Then you need to remove the 2 lines that adjust EDI and EAX from the start of `.LOAD_IMAGE_PRE` so it should start with:

```
.LOAD_IMAGE_PRE:

    ; get starting cluster

    push    word ROOT_SEG                ; root segment loc
```

You didn't provide a `loader.asm` file so as an example I used this for testing:

```
org 0x200
bits 16

jmp start

%include "include/io.inc" 

start:
    BiosPrint hello
    jmp $

hello: db "Hello, world!", 0
```

I used `org 0x200` because you used a near jump from your bootloader to reach this and your bootloader is using a *CS* of 0x07c0. That means the offset (ORG) that is needed for stage2 is still relative to 0x07c0 which is why I use 0x200. 0x07c0:0x0200 is physical address 0x07e00 which is the physical address right after the bootloader.

When I run it in BOCHS I get this output:

[image]